# R Shiny: Using numeric output variable as the initial value of slider

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

My shiny app looks like this:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Basic dashboard"),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    
    fluidRow(
      box(plotOutput("plot1", height = 250)),
      
      box(textInput("my_text",  # supposed to be a numeric input
                    "Text input:"),
        title = "Controls",
        sliderInput("slider",
                    "Number of observations:",
                    min = 1, max = 100,
                    value = 50 # Want it to be output$my_init
                    )
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  set.seed(122)
  histdata <- rnorm(500)
  
  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    data <- histdata[seq_len(input$slider)]
    hist(data)
  })
  
# My attempt
# output$my_init <- input$my_text + 28
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I want to set the initial value of the slider as `output$my_init`, a numeric variable that will be the result of operating some input variables. I tried using `renderPrint`, but the output is not numeric.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That will not work. Have a look a `updateSliderInput`. See e.g. https://mastering-shiny.org/action-dynamic.html

Answer (score 2):

I piggybacked on @stefan's comments and came up with this answer:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Basic dashboard"),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    
    fluidRow(
      box(plotOutput("plot1", height = 250)),
      
      box(numericInput("my_num", "Numeric input:", value = 50),
          title = "Controls",
          sliderInput("slider",
                      "Number of observations:",
                      min = 1, max = 100,
                      value = 50 # Want it to be output$my_init
          )
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  set.seed(122)
  histdata <- rnorm(500)
  
  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    data <- histdata[seq_len(input$slider)]
    hist(data)
  })
  
  # My attempt
  observeEvent(input$my_num, {
    updateSliderInput(inputId = "slider", value = input$my_num)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

The idea is to use `observeEvent()` to trigger `updateSliderInput()` (update slider input widget) and update the value parameter of `sliderInput()`

Comment: Please explain a bit what you changed and why. That would help future users a lot.

Comment: Thanks, Howard. However, I want the initial value of the slider to depend not directly on an input variable, but on an operation on it (or on the other input variables). Say, for instance, input$my_num + input$slider.